# Корректное отображение данных

Tags: c++, qt

В файле конфиг у меня лежат данные:

```
6.30
0.92
1111
1
11.80
2222
2
11.80
58.00
50.8
```

но у меня проблема с тем что при нажатии кнопки у меня заполняются данные, но *не точно*.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    FILE *fid=fopen("config.ini","rt");

    if(fid)
    {
        double val=0;
        char str[255];
        fscanf(fid,"%lf",&val);
        qDebug() << val;
        ui->sb_dal_izl_gidrof->setValue(val);

        fscanf(fid,"%lf",&val);
        ui->sb_dal_priem_gidrof->setValue(val);

        fscanf(fid,"%s", &str);
        ui->le_tipIzmGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));

        fscanf(fid,"%s", &str);
        ui->le_namIzmGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));
        //Если это сторка
       // char str[0]=0;

        fscanf(fid,"%lf", &val);
        ui->sb_chywstIzmGidrofon2->setValue(val);


        fscanf(fid,"s", &str);
        ui->le_tipPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));

        fscanf(fid,"s", &str);
        ui->le_namPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));

        fscanf(fid,"lf", &val);
        ui->sb_chywstPriemGidrofon2->setValue(val);
        fclose(fid);
        }
     }
```

На выходе:

```
fscanf(fid,"s", &str);
ui->le_tipPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));

fscanf(fid,"s", &str);
ui->le_namPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));
```

Имеют значение `1` и `1` . А надо `2222` и `2`.

Сначала я подумал, что буфер `str` заполнен, и  поэтому решил очистить его `srt[0]=0;` и `srt[255]=0;`, но не вышло. Результат был тот же.

Потом решил в вести просто новый буфер для этих двух переменных

```
double val=0;
char str[255];
char str1[255]; // вот новый буфер 

// а тут его новое использование 
fscanf(fid,"s", &str1);
ui->le_tipPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str1));

fscanf(fid,"s", &str1);
ui->le_namPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str1));
```

Результат весьма печальный `^Cj` и `^Cj` - вот, что он выдал мне на выходе.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы выводило то, что написано в файле, а не кракозябры?

Comment: Вы так и пишете - `fscanf(fid,"s", &str1);`? Т.е. `"s"`, а не `"%s"`? И, кстати, можете не писать `&` при строках - адрес строки будет передан и так...

Comment: И вообще использовать QString и отказаться от fscanf и подобных низкоуровневых строковых функций работая с с++ и Qt.

Comment: Прикладываю пример работы с файлами и строками в Qt: http://pastebin.com/RiBdrW6S

Comment: @gil9red спасибо буду знать ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harry  спосибо вы ответили на мой вопрос наводящем вопросом .
"s", а не "%s"?

я поставил %s  и вернул str в место str1

```
    fscanf(fid,"%s", &str);
    ui->le_tipPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));

    fscanf(fid,"%s", &str);
    ui->le_namPriemGidr2->setText(QString("%1").arg(str));
```

и все заработало :3 Спасибо , до перебичинiя